# Laravel/OctoberCMS File validation not working AT ALL

Tags: php, image, laravel, validation, octobercms

I have added a single file upload and a multiple file upload in a form.
Now, everything is working perfectly fine.

EXCEPT the validation for the files.

I am trying to validate to see if the uploaded file is an image, but it is just not validating at all and just passing the files as if they have no issues.
This is what my validation looks like, cover and image_gallery are the uploads I am trying to validate.
I am working on OctoberCMS, which uses Laravel.
I have tried different combinations of image and mimes, nothing is working at all.

```
$data = post();

$rules = [          
    'name' => 'required|unique:lesyt_novels_,name',
    'slug' => 'required|unique:lesyt_novels_,slug',
    'cover' => 'image',
    'description' => 'required',
    'image_gallery' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
];
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
```

Comment: Are the images itselves actually being uploaded? If not you might be missing the  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` value in your `form`  tag

Comment: are you sure that $data contains the files?

Comment: I am able to upload the files. There is no problem with that. And I can also validate the other things in $data, all except the files. Currently i used a function to do a validation myself and used $validator->after.

Comment: Hi @Lesyt Did you find a solution for this yet?